# Attempting to use source() in r, but gives grep error

Tags: r, network-programming, muxviz

I am attempting to use [Muxviz](http://www.muxviz.net), and I believe that I installed all of the required dependencies (octave, R, g++, gfortan, and GDAL), but I'm getting an error when I try to use "source('muxVizGUI.R')". I says

```
Error in if (grep("3.2", version$version.string) != 1) { : 
argument is of length zero
```

Any suggestions? I just made sure that R is > 3.2.x.

Comment: You should look at the script you're calling, but it also looks like you need R < 3.3.x.

Comment: could you please provide a reproducible example? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that, considering I think this is happening only with this one file.